# Firebase Statics Listeners

Tags: java, android, firebase

Firebase is running as Static with `setAndroidContext();` Now I am wondering how I can resolve a problem WITHOUT having to make a pointer to a Listener and doing 
`firebase.removeListener(Thelistener)`

I would like to know if there is a way to Remove all Listeners as Statics, but the question has been asked before and answered that there is no way for now to Remove all Listeners.

So we go to an alternative... Is there a way to reset all of the Statics listeners that has been set by the Firebase in Android.

I have tried to setAndroidContext(null) before I recreate a ApplicationContext and re-assign the `setAndroidContext()`, but it is still there. Since in a case, it is Static.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. Can you add the minimum code that shows the problem you have?

Comment: I will add the Code for later, because it is quite messy to add for now. I will take my time to post it later. But let me explain the problem. I have a Bound Service that have a Method to Create a FireBase Connection. It is fired when logging in to the app. Now when logging off, I try to call stopSelf() on the Service on unBind() of the Service. So technically the Service will be destroyed. The problem is, FireBase Listeners is Created on the Context itself, so when I relogin, the Activity is recreated and there will be 2 Instance of Listeners.